# Upload big buildpack fail because cloud foundry cc nginx timeout

Tags: nginx, cloud-foundry

I have a question about blobstore uploading. Our Dotnet buildpack size is very large. > 1GB. and when I upload blobostore, I got an error:

```
Uploading buildpack dotnet-core as admin...
 0 B / 1016.63 MiB [-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]   0.00%REQUEST: [2019-05-13T04:30:29-04:00]
PUT /v2/buildpacks/5379e97f-4423-4330-bb7e-8036b4c48709/bits HTTP/1.1
Host: api.eugb-sz-cluster.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud
Accept: application/json
Authorization: [PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=12245ea06b3db302992d5b3e9353714083e5aa46c014170c2ca8db40c1ca
User-Agent: cf/6.41.0+dd4c76cdd.2018-11-28 (go1.11.2; amd64 linux)
[multipart/form-data Content Hidden]

 1016.63 MiB / 1016.63 MiB [=======================================================================================================================================================================] 100.00%RESPONSE: [2019-05-13T04:32:06-04:00]
HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Time-out
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Mon, 13 May 2019 08:32:06 GMT
<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>




error seeking a stream on retry: Unexpected Response
Response code: 504
CC code:       0
CC error code:
Description:   <html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

FAILED
```

I think it because some timeout configration, cc have not finished the buildpack to blobstore. then nginx report timeout then fail the uploading.

I tried some nginx config, like:

```
proxy_ignore_client_abort  on;
fastcgi_connect_timeout  600s;
fastcgi_send_timeout  600s;
fastcgi_read_timeout  600s;
proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
proxy_send_timeout 600s;
proxy_read_timeout 600s;
```

But they ALL don't work.... Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I also see this error in nignix access log:


api.eugb-sz-cluster.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud - [13/May/2019:07:47:22 +0000] "PUT /v2/buildpacks/df39fa81-422b-405c-bc23-bc25597de277/bits HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "cf/6.41.0+dd4c76cdd.2018-11-28 (go1.11.2; amd64 linux)" 10.113.169.167, 172.30.245.193 vcap_request_id:- userid:ab96d055-f489-4616-9b42-b6f3111c39a2 clientid:cf response_time:-

Comment: How long does it take before the upload fails? That might help you find where it's failing, as it could fail in a number of spots like your external LB, Gorouter, Cloud Controller's Nginx, or I supposed talking to the blobstore. Usually these failures happen client side though, and because the client's upload speed is too slow. If you want a quick and dirty fix, just upload from somewhere with a faster connection or from a jumpbox that's on the same network as your foundation. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Daniel! I found the buildpack is uploaded to Cloud Controller. I should fail at cc upload it to remote blobstore. So I cannot try it from a jumpbox or somewhere... :( And it fail after 1mins I think when upload from cc to blobstore. But I didn't see that 60s config in cc or nignx config ....

Comment: And I found, Nginx reports timeout every time when the upload time **> 60s** from cc to fog blobstore, but the buildpack should be uploaded to blobstore after 60s:
`{"message":"blobstore.cp-finish","log_level":"info","source":"cc.blobstore","data":{"request_guid":"xxx","destination_key":"xxx","duration_seconds":62.663199582,"size":1073996731},"thread_id":xxx,"fiber_id":xxx,"process_id":23529,"file":"/var/vcap/packages/xxx/cloud_controller_ng/lib/cloud_controller/blobstore/fog/fog_client.rb","lineno":78,"method":"cp_to_blobstore"}`

So maybe there is some nginx timeout configuration is 60s?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I found the root cause, there is a 60s timeout on my upstream load balancer. I increase it. and now, it works. thanks a lot!